# Extracting object volume in eCognition?

Tags: ecognition, volume

I am a beginner in eCognition and am working on trying to extract volume for certain classified objects. When I extract volume with the ruleset given in the program it is the same value as the area (ie. 200m2 for area and 200m3 for volume). From what I understand in the handbook there needs to be voxels available to create a 3D volume. I am currently using a handful of DEM derivatives (slope, roughness, aspect, a change map, curvature) and the DEM itself.

Can anyone suggest a way to determine volume in eCognition (or any alternative methods)?

[image: I am trying to pull out the individual volume of the brown and green objects. They are landslides and their deposits.]

[image: I want be able to get a correct volume so upon exporting in eCog with the attribute table they can be seen on the pop-up from ArcGIS (ignore my values in the Arc pop-up, they are wrong)]

Comment: Volume of what objects? What are your data? Can you post an image and a desired result?

Comment: Hi Jon, I just posted some pics above. I am trying to determine the volume of landslides (lost material) and their deposits (gained material). My data are a change map from subtracted (1meterx1meter) DEMs, Slope, 2012 DEM(1x1m) of the area, Openness, Roughness, Curvature, NDVI, satellite imagery, and streamlines. The volume I keep getting for the objects is the same as the area as seen in the first image - which I believe is incorrect. In the end I just want to correct volume so I can add it to the attribute table and export into ArcGIS so it can be seen in the table and pop-up (bottom image).

Comment: The volumes I have in the pop-up image are to be ignored because they are incorrect. That was just me trying to figure it out.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out through arc by using a py script with zonal stats to table and calculating the fields instead